# Interface implementation generic method c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics, interface

I wanted to make some basic controller. In this controller I would like to have common functions (Create, Edit, Delete,...) - each controller for different model and then BasicController would work with interface.

I wanted to have interface which will be implemented in each model to have access to common functions:

```
public interface IModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Task CreateAsync<T>(string userName, T model) where T: IModel;
        public Task<bool> EditAsync<T>(string userName, T model) where T: IModel;

        public bool CreateValidation();
        public bool EditValidation();
    }
```

Then I implement the Interface in one Model:

```
public class TestResult : IHasFile, IIsReserved, IModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public async Task CreateAsync<T>(string resolverGID, T model) where T: TestResultModel
        {
            //do stuff

        }

        public async Task<bool> EditAsync<T>(string resolverGID,T model) where T: TestResultModel
        {
            //do stuff
        }
        ...
    }
public class TestResultModel : TestResult
    {
        [Display(Name = "ATTACHMENTS")]
        public List<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile> File { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "USED_STANDARDS")]
        public string[] UsedStandardsAsArray { get; set; }
    }
```

I suppose, that TestResultModel has to implement IModel as well when it is based on TestResult, but I get error:

> Error CS0425  The constraints for type parameter 'T' of method
> 'TestResult.EditAsync(string, T)' must match the constraints for
> type parameter 'T' of interface method 'IModel.EditAsync(string,
> T)'. Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead.

I have tried to change the interface to:

```
public interface IModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Task CreateAsync<T>(string userName, T model) where T: class;
        public Task<bool> EditAsync<T>(string userName, T model) where T: class;

        public bool CreateValidation();
        public bool EditValidation();
    }
```

but still not working.

Do you know how to handle this issue? What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks for hints.

**EDIT:**
tried also:

```
public interface IModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Task CreateAsync(string userName, IModel model);
        public Task<bool> EditAsync(string userName, IModel model);

        public bool CreateValidation();
        public bool EditValidation();
    }
```

and then:

```
public async Task CreateAsync(string resolverGID, TestResultModel model)
        {
            //do stuff

        }

        public async Task<bool> EditAsync(string resolverGID,TestResultModel model)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
        ...
    }
```

but then Interface is not implemented...

Comment: The constraints must match to the interface... so `where T: IModel;` must be both on the interface and on the implementing class (doesn't work with `where T:something that implements IModel`)

Comment: It looks like you want to constrain interface implementations to return `SAMETYPE` which is, I'm afraid, a mythical keyword.

Comment: Consider https://dotnetfiddle.net/ueQPg4

Comment: @mjwills Exactly what I was going to suggest. Having typeparams and constraints only on some methods, as opposed to the interface itself, is generally a code smell for me.

Comment: @mjwills Exactly what I wanted!! Thank you!